# La respuesta de una petición get me regresa algunos datos que son de tipo int a string

Tags: php, laravel, json, api

Hola gracias a todos por su apoyo.

La cuestión es que tengo un API laravel ya montada en un hosting, y cuando hago una solicitud post desde mi aplicación de Android recibo algunos datos que son int y me los regresa como string "333", al principio pensé que era la logica de parte de la aplicación pero al hacer la petición con postman me di cuenta que en realidad era por parte de la api, me gustaría destacar que la misma API en local si me regresa los datos correctos, a continuación les comparto un fragmento de la respuesta:

```
{
"paginate": {
    "total": 9,
    "current_page": 1,
    "per_page": 15,
    "last_page": 1,
    "from": 1,
    "to": 1
},
"products": {
    "current_page": 1,
    "data": [
         {
            "id": 51,
            "name": "sfsdfsdf",
            "price": "123",
            "desc": "asdasdasd",
            "unit": "paquete",
            "img": "1606592605productoimage.png",
            "created_at": "2020-11-28T19:43:25.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-11-28T19:43:25.000000Z",
            "sin_delantal": "0"
        },
```

LO QUE SE ME HACE CURIOSO ES QUE EL ID ES DE TIPO INT Y ESTE SI LO REGRESA COMO TAL. Los datos que no me regresa de manera correcta son: Price[int] y sin_delanta[tinyint], les agradecería cualquier ayuda que me puedieran proporcionar.

Comment: lo siento la peticion es get, un error de dedo

Comment: todo depende de cómo tengas la api construida, si te es posible pega también el código donde construyes tu api con laravel para ver si hay un posible error, también otra sugerencia es que te fijes si los tipos de campos de tu base de datos en producción son iguales que los de desarrollo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generalmente, las consultas a base de datos, devuelven todas las columnas como cadena, independientemente del tipo definido al crear la tabla; pero tiene fácil solución: Cuando generes el arreglo como JSON, simplemente agrega la opción *JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK* para **convertir a número** las cadenas que representan números:

```
$data = [
  "products" => [
    "current_page" => 1,
    "data" => [
         [
            "id" => "51",
            "name" => "sfsdfsdf",
            "price" => "123",
            "desc" => "asdasdasd",
            "unit" => "paquete",
            "img" => "1606592605productoimage.png",
            "created_at" => "2020-11-28T19:43:25.000000Z",
            "updated_at" => "2020-11-28T19:43:25.000000Z",
            "sin_delantal" => "0"
        ]
      ]
  ]
];

echo json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Resultado:

```
{
  "products": {
    "current_page": 1,
    "data": [
         {
            "id": 51,
            "name": "sfsdfsdf",
            "price": 123,
            "desc": "asdasdasd",
            "unit": "paquete",
            "img": "1606592605productoimage.png",
            "created_at": "2020-11-28T19:43:25.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-11-28T19:43:25.000000Z",
            "sin_delantal": 0
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

Referencia: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php#example-4490

Answer (score 0):

Luego de estar 2 días estancado en este problema encontré la solución en otra pregunta en StackOverflow en ingles:

Básicamente tienes que agregar al modelo de tu clase los $casts que necesites:

`protected $casts = [ 'imdb_rating' => 'float', 'imdb_votes' => 'integer' ];`

De esta manera puedes convertir los datos de las respuestas a los tipos de da que necesites.
[Link a la respuesta original.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527050/laravel-5-controller-sending-json-integer-as-string]

Comment: En el enlace original se menciona lo que hace el código. No olvides hacer lo mismo en tu respuesta :) Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.